# How to make "Identify browser as" in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, browser, identify

I am writing a browser for iOS (iPad) and I was wondering how I could make a user setting that will make the browser seem as if it was Safari Desktop, Firefox, etc. (I am a beginner) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"custom user agent", @"UserAgent", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionary];
[dictionary release];
```

before you create your web view may work.

Comment: I just tried this but nothing happened. For the User Agent I did `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8F190 Safari/6533.18.5` It still acts as though the browser is Safari for iPhone. Please help. Thank you

Comment: I think it's important that you run that code before you create a web view. So if you load the web view from a nib it might be too late. YOu could try the approach in this post instead: http://blog.hawkey.org/?p=347